# Django database data delete and backup

Tags: django

I have a Django project. Some data is restored in the Model database. But in the web, there is some function to delete such data.

However, I don't want to complete delete such data for possible further usage like statistics. How could deal with such issues normally? I can think about transferring such data to another Model database before deleting, but is it too complicated? Or any other suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by the _new demonstration in the page_?

Comment: just to delete the old data as the updation

Comment: What is an _updation_ in your case? You want to test your database or you mean something else?

Comment: I mean just delete it. But I want to still have the backup of it.

Comment: Well, you can add new field which is `False` by default, something like `deleted` and then instead of deleting you can set this field to true and then just query all objects that have `deleted = False`